# searchBar in nav Symfony 5.4

Tags: php, symfony, render, searchbar

I'm a beginner ;)

I'm trying to have a searchBar form in a navbar located in base.twig.html, searching for the game just by it's name.

But i can't get any results when typing in the form in navbar. The functions in repo and controller are correct, I checked it with "dd".

This is my controller:

```
[Route('/search/SBresult', name: 'app_search')]

public function searchBar(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, string $Nazwa='Nazwa'):Response
 {
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder([])
    ->add('Nazwa', TextType::class, ['required' => false, 'label' => 'wpisz nazwę gry', 
   'label_attr'=> ['class'=>'text-white ps-3'], 'attr' => ['class'=>'form-control form- 
    control-lg']])
   
    ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);
                 
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) 
    
    { 
       
        $Nazwa = $form->get('Nazwa')->getData(); 
        //dd($Nazwa);
       
        $Gry = $entityManager->getRepository(Gra::class)->findGra($Nazwa);

       //dd($Gry);
      return $this->render('search/SBresult.html.twig', ['Gry' => $Gry]);
      //return $this->redirectToRoute('app_search', ['Gry' => $Gry], Response:: HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
  
   }     
    return $this->render('search/searchBar.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView()]); 
    }
```

I have a template search/SBresult.html.twig with  a proper  {% for Gry in Gry %}

And this is how I render the form in base.twig.html:
`{{render (controller('App\\Controller\\SearchController::searchBar'))}}`

I think that the problem lies in rendering the form in a navbar, because I've already made a searchform with many options to choose, exactly the same way, and it works. But this form is rendered in its own template, not in base.

What should I do to get the results from the searchBar in base.twig.html?